# sanitizeHtml with marked doesn't render special characters correctly (& is &amp; and then &amp;amp)

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, sanitization, javascript-marked

I'm trying to render user input using `SvelteMarkdown` (that uses [marked](https://marked.js.org/)).

The steps are:

1. user input is sanitized using [sanitizeHtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html)
2. sanitized user input goes to `SvelteMarkdown` to be rendered in `html`

The problem is that it does not render special characters as they should be displayed. It is because they are converted two times.

1. input "Tom & Jerry"
2. `sanitizeHtml("Tom & Jerry")` > `"Tom &amp; Jerry"` - *this is the format that browser needs to render it correctly*
3. `SvelteMarkdown("Tom &amp; Jerry")` > `"Tom &amp;amp; Jerry"`

Not sure how to make this work while preserving safety measures. When I don't use `sanitizeHtml`, many things can go bad, for example `<img src='x' onerror='alert("XSS")'>` opens alert window after the content is rendered.

What I want to do is to render some characters like "<", ">", "&" etc but still be "safe" as I work with user generated content.

Are there any solutions?

Comment: You could write your own wrapper around `marked` (done that before myself) and do things in the correct order, i.e. convert MD to HTML, then sanitize it. Also, a Markdown rendering component probably should have sanitization built-in as an option.

Comment: @H.B. I'm not very experienced in this area but yes, it has some sanitization built-in but I'm not sure if it's safe as content like this "<img src='x' onerror='alert("XSS")'>" spawns alert for any user that reads/see the comment. That's why I think I need to use the sanitizeHtml too.